# Javascript function using the "+=" operator

Tags: javascript

I'm studying for an HTML certification an ran across a syntax like this:

```
 foo.click() += some_other_function;   // supposedly to invoke another function
                                       // when the foo HTML element is clicked.
```

I can't find any information on this.  Can this be done in JavaScript?

Comment: So, you want to learn how to bind event handlers? See http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html . `+=` is for summation and string concatenation.

Comment: Looks like C#-ish syntax for adding event handlers to event collections, but this can't be done natively in JS.

Comment: I... don't think thats valid javascript

Comment: Where exactly have you seen that syntax?

Comment: This is a syntax error.  This *would be* equivalent to `foo.click() = foo.click() + some_other_function`, and you (obviously) can't assign a value to `foo.click()`.

Comment: You might want to search Stack Overflow as well: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+bind+event+handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the `x += y` operation in javascript is just shorthand for `x = x + y`

Using this with a function call, makes little sense. There is probably some contrived way to make the code you posted *not error*, but its hard to imagine where it could do something meaningful.

So:

> Can this be done in JavaScript?

No, not really.

Comment: Not the fact that it will return `NaN` because you're mixing undefined with `some_other_function`. And it is also illegal to assign value to a function in JavaScript.